# Google Geocoder Missing Type Address Component

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, geocoding

I am stumped at the moment with the Google Geocoder. Right now, if I query by address, "New York City, NY", I get back results that say the types of the result is "types":["locality","political"] but there is no locality in the address_components. If I query "Tempe, AZ", same thing. If I search for a state, the types is administrative_area_level_1 but it only gives me the country in the address_compenents. Any ideas?

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({'address': "New York City, NY"}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         //do stuff
    } else {
        console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
```

My results for "New York City, NY"

```
[{"address_components":[{"long_name":"New York","short_name":"NY","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"United States","short_name":"US","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"New York, USA","geometry":{"bounds":{"south":40.4773991,"west":-74.25908989999999,"north":40.9175771,"east":-73.7002721},"location":{"lat":40.7127837,"lng":-74.00594130000002},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"south":40.4960439,"west":-74.2557349,"north":40.9152555,"east":-73.7002721}},"place_id":"ChIJOwg_06VPwokRYv534QaPC8g","types":["locality","political"]}]
```

I am confused as why it is telling me it is type city (locality), but missing the locality attribute. I would expect the locality to be there with the value, "New York" and the formatted address to include the locality in it.  Thanks!

Comment: What are you asking?  What are you expecting for a "locality"?  The result of type `["locality","political"]` is "New York", the state is long_name: "New York" or short_name: "NY".

Comment: I guess I am asking why is the locality attribute missing when I search for New York City, NY?

Comment: I edited my original to show my results.

Comment: We are also having the same issue right now with the geocoder not returning city.

Comment: The first address_component I get is `{"long_name": "New York","short_name": "New York","types": ["locality","political"]}` (on [this page](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=New%20York%20City,%20NY&geocode=1)) [not the same as what you posted] maybe there is an issue with the server that is replying to your request (or maybe a broken version is in being rolled out, or reverted)

Comment: @geocodezip http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Las%20Vegas,%20NV
When you go there you can see under formatted address that it is showing `Clark County, NV, USA` instead of `Las Vegas, NV, USA`.

Comment: Thanks for commenting @LelandCope. You have helped me not think I am crazy.

Comment: Thanks for weighing in @geocodezip. Do you know if stuff like this normally happens? I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Not for me.  The first entry is: `{"long_name" : "Las Vegas","short_name" : "Las Vegas","types" : [ "locality", "political" ]}`, which implies it is server specific; the server you are getting your data is doing something different from the server I am getting data from.  This happens sometimes, usually when google is making a change.

Comment: Oh okay, interesting. So you think they are aware? If not, do you suggest somewhere we can make a ticket. Thanks again for the help :)

Comment: @LelandCope Are you still having the issue?

Comment: So that website that you posted @geocodezip, I get different results as you, the broken ones. So this could mean that people using my site might not be experiencing the same problem? I am just worried about user experience right now.

Comment: Yes.  My guess (as I don't see the issue) is that it is server related.  As I said before, when Google's servers behave differently, it is usually only for a short time as they roll out some new version (or rollback a problematic release).

Comment: possibly related issue in the issue tracker: [Issue 10880: Bug: locality doesn't received for Brooklyn street](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10880)

Comment: Interesting. Yeah, could be though mine isn't locality specific. If I do a geocode with address on a street_address search, it is missing the street_address from the address components. If I search for a city, the locality is missing. If I search for a state, the administrative_area_level_1 is missing. I commented there saying I am having a problem too so thanks for the link!

Comment: @RobertGarcia it looks like its fixed for us. Just tried the link I posted above and everything looks like it is supposed to.

Comment: @LelandCope Yep, you are right. Same here. Whew! Hopefully that doesn't happen again. That was pretty terrible.

Answer (score 5):

Never assume that `"locality"`, or any other type, will always be present in address components.

See [gmaps-api-issues #3320](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3320#c21) and the longer explanation in the [Place Autocomplete Address Form](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) example.

If you really need a specific component, [reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding) is the only reliable way to get it always (that is, in places where it actually exists).